# Set Default Strtotime

Tags: php, time, strtotime

I want to create a demo version of an already functioning data site. To make things quick and easy, I am going to duplicate my site, but I want to fix the time so it reads the same items from the databases every time I present the demo.

To aid this I want to fix strtotime to say September 31st 2016. Any ideas please?

Comment: Change the data in your database

Comment: make a custom string to time function that you can override the value when you want. function mystrtotime() { return 'yourtime'; // return strtotime;}

Comment: @Brett this question seems resolved judging by the upvote on your comment, but isn't answered and still appears in the unanswered list.  Please post your comment as an answer so Kane can accept it.

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks, have done so below

Comment: @KaneVincent to tie up this loose end, please accept the newly posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a custom string to time function that you can override the value when you want.

```
function mystrtotime() { 
    // Remove the return strtotime on your demo site, but leave it in on the real site
    return 'yourtime'; // return strtotime; 
}
```